# subclassing property raising TypeError on __init__

Tags: python, concurrency, properties

I've subclassed property to try to add a lock to it so access to it is atomic(only one thread can read and write to it at one time). But I'm running into errors with the initializer and can't figure out why.

To be clear: I don't want to make a descriptor, I want to be able to use @atomic_property decorator instead of @property

```
class atomic_property(property):

    def __init__(self, func, name=None, doc=None):
        self.__name__ = name or func.__name__
        self.__module__ = func.__module__
        self.__doc__ = doc or func.__doc__
        self.func = func
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        with self.lock:
            return self.func(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        with self.lock:
            return self.func(obj, value)
```

Here is the traceback from ipython.

```
    In [12]: class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._b = 1
    @utils.atomic_property
    def b(self):
        return self._b
    @b.setter
    def b(self, val):
        self._b = val
   ....:         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-daec89385bc3> in <module>()
----> 1 class a(object):
      2     def __init__(self):
      3         self._b = 1
      4     @utils.atomic_property
      5     def b(self):

<ipython-input-12-daec89385bc3> in a()
      5     def b(self):
      6         return self._b
----> 7     @b.setter
      8     def b(self, val):
      9         self._b = val

TypeError: __init__() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: your `__init__` is conflicting with `property.__init__` which (I assume) is trying to be called when you use `b.setter` but the signature is wrong.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen how would I fix it to use the right __init__?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to subclass `property` to implement descriptors. Any class with `__get__`, `__set__` or `__del__` are a valid descriptor classes

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini will I be able to annotate with '@myproperty' still?

Comment: `@something` is called a decorator. Any callable (anything that implements `__call__`) can be a decorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are far from properly subclassing `property` with your code: for once
you rewrite some methods, but never care to call the upstream method so it can do its business.

Not that it can't be done this way, if you actually reproduce in your subclass all behaviors the methods on the superclass would perform - but even without looking at the code of the superclass (which in cPython's case is in native code) - one can see that either `self.func` is the getter function, or it is the setter function - it can't be both.

If you just care to annotate the attributes you will  use and perform the actions you want, and delegate the remainder to the original code, it will very
likely just work:

```
class atomic_property(property):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kw):
        super(atomic_property, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type):
        with self.lock:
            return super(atomic_property, self).__get__(obj, objtype)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        with self.lock:
            return super(atomic_property, self).__set__(obj, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using `property.setter` calls the `__init__` again, which seems odd (initialize the same object more then once?)

Anyway you need to let `property` do it's job, how do you expect it to work correctly if you don't use `property.__init__` at all?  You could do something like this for example:

```
class atomic_property(property):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #print(args,kwargs) #uncomment to see this be called again when using .setter !
        super(atomic_property,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)       
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        with self.lock:
            return super(atomic_property,self).__get__(obj,objtype)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        with self.lock:
            return super(atomic_property,self).__set__(obj,value)
```